# validar datos exceptuando el selector que triggereo Jquery

Tags: jquery

Quiero que cuando salga del campo valide si no esta el mismo dato repetido en otro input. Aquí mi código y mi avance

```
<input type="text" class="num_valido">
<input type="text" class="num_valido">
<input type="text" class="num_valido">
<input type="text" class="num_valido">
<input type="text" class="num_valido">
<input type="text" class="num_valido">
<input type="text" class="num_valido">
<input type="text" class="num_valido">
<input type="text" class="num_valido">
<input type="text" class="num_valido">

<script>
$(document).on('blur','.num_valido',function(){
  var value = $(this).val(); //SACAMOS EL VALOR
var that = this;
  if (!$.isNumeric(value)) //VALIDAMOS SI ES UN NUMERO
  {
    $(this).val($(this).data('')); //NO LO ES LO DEJAMOS EN BLANCO
  }

  else
  {
    if (value <= 0 || value > 10) //EL NUMERO DEBE ESTAR ENTRE 1 Y 10
    {
      $(this).val($(this).data('')); // SI NO LO DEJAMOS EN BLANCO
    }

    else
    {
      $('.num_valido').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == value)
        {
          $(this).val($(this).data('')); //LO DEJAMOS EN BLANCO SI YA ESTA EN OTRO input
          return false; //CERRAMOS EL CICLO
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

El problema es que también me está validando el mismo campo de donde está detectando el blur, y obvio me está limpiando el campo por que si existe en el recorrido de los "num_valido". ¿Cómo le hago para validar todos excepto del que estoy triggereando el blur?

EDITO RESPUESTA

```
  $('.num_valido').each(function(){
    if (that != this)
    {
      if ($(this).val() == value)
      {
          $(this).val($(this).data(''));
          return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

Diferencié that de this arriba la declaré. Que les sirva. Gracias a yorodm que me dió la idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que cuando haces esto:

```
$('.num_valido').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == value)
        {
          $(this).val($(this).data('')); //LO DEJAMOS EN BLANCO SI YA ESTA EN OTRO input
          return false; //CERRAMOS EL CICLO
        }
      });
```

recorres también el elemento que lanzó el `blur`. Ya que antes de ejecutar la iteración tienes a tienes a `this` como la referencia al elemento del `blur` pudieras aprovechar y hacer algo como:

```
   that = this; // para guardar el actual
   elementos_a_verificar = $.grep($('.num_valido'),function(n,i){
     // filtrar aqui utilizando that
     return ! $(that).is(n);
   });
```

y despúes iterar sobre `elementos_a_verificar`. Tengo mis dudas sobre el uso de `is` en este contexto pero asi de memoria es lo más parecido a operador de igualdad que sirve para selectores.